# node sql server insert data to a tabel

Tags: python, node.js, sql-server, node-mssql

I have a website how has a form I'd like to get the post data (I already did it) and put it in a database.

The data come as a JSON, and it looks like this:

```
{ name : "text" , ho : "text" , day : number , m : number }
```

I also have a SQL server table how has the same columns name meaning:

- Col1 = name (`nvarchar`)
- Col2 = ho (`nvarchar`)
- Col3 = day (`numeric`)
- Col4 = m (`numeric`)

I am tring to insert data to the data base using nodejs and mssql moudeul.

My code looks like this:

```
    let config = {/*the info*/}
    //connect to the data base
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config , function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    //get the keys and the values
    let colsName enter code here= Object.keys(theDataObj);
    let values = []
    for(let i = 0; i < colsName.length; i++){
         values.push(theDataObj[colsName[i]]);
         console.log(theDataObj[colsName[i]])//check to see what going in
   pool.request().query(`INSERT INTO ${tabelName}(${colsName}) VALUES (${values})` , function(err , result){
 if(err) throw err;
 console.log(result)
});
    }

});
```

Every time I am trying to run this code doesn't matter if i change stuff it's send me back the same error:

> there is no col name ${values[0]}

I am meaning the value this statement has.

The value in the array values in position 0 or sometimes 1.

If someone know about a way I can insert data to sql tabel it will save me. In the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#prepare-statement-callback) there is no good expansion to this.

I am coming from python background when I want to add data like this to a table I am using python pandas df to_sql and setting the sleeting to add the data and not overwrite this.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from SQL Server 2016 native json support is available (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)).

If you are using SQL Server 2016 (or later) you can pass the entire json to SQL Server and read the data stored in the json with `openjson` and the clause `with` (this will let you specify the structure of your json). Then you can insert into your table:

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '{ "name" : "text" , "ho" : "text" , "day" : 1 , "m" : 10}'

insert into YOUR_TABLE
select  Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 
from openjson(@json)
with(   
    Col1 nvarchar(50) '$.name' ,  
    Col2 nvarchar(50) '$.ho',  
    Col3 numeric      '$.day',  
    Col4 numeric      '$.m'  
)
```

Please note that your json is not valid: you are missing quotes around key names. A valid version of your json should be:

```
{ "name" : "text" , "ho" : "text" , "day" : number , "m" : number }
```